# Can't add a user to a group in Google workspace

Tags: google-workspace, workspace

I'm adding a user to a group in Google workspace using web-console, got "The user has been added to the group" message, but no group appeared in group membership box [see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sGv.png)
If I'm trying vice versa I got an error "The following member can not be added to *the_group* because it is already a member of *the_group*:".
How can I fix it?

Comment: Insert the image in the post instead of linking to an external resource which may die.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI for the Admin Console may not be updated real-time.  What I would suggest is to go back to the group window, and refresh your screen to verify the email address is actually part of the group.  Wait a few minutes, and the group should appear in the user record list as well.